# Client authentication with java client talking to a .Net webservice - verification error

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, ssl

I am writing a java web service client that talks to a .Net web service (.Net v4). I have SSL working, but I have issues with the client authentication.

The client certificate was given to me as a pfx file. I imported this into a keystore jks file.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KS_WIN); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", KS_Password); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
```

The error I am getting is

```
"An error occurred when verifying security for the message"
```

The SSL definitely works as it when we turn client authentication off it works well, but when we turn

Comment: "..was given to me as a pfx file. I imported this into a keystore jks file." What was (is) the output of your import?

Comment: I imported the pfx from the .Net programmer into a new client.jks file. I used the keytool command. If I do a list in keytool I can see the jks file has the certificate. I also added the Root CA because I read somewhere that may be the issue.